# How to change Date format in excel?

Tags: excel, date, time

In my excel file, the format is something like "Sun Nov 01 09:54:40 IST 2015".

I want this like 01-Nov-2015 only.

I tried but it does not changing. Ctrl+1, select date and then choose format. But it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the date use this formula:

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,9,2)&"-"&MID(A1,5,3)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,4)).
```

Then format it like @harun24hr stated. Use a custom format `dd-mmm-yyyy`.

to do it all in one formula (the conversion and format):

```
=TEXT(--(MID(A1,9,2)&" "&MID(A1,5,3)&" "&RIGHT(A1,4)),"dd-mmm-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply `dd-mmm-yyyy` this format in your cell. You can also use this function `=TEXT(B2,"dd-mmm-yyyy")` to get your desired format.

[image]

Comment: But it can't replace the cell with new date format, that is the problem.

Comment: Do you mean replace cell data or format? This will only replace your format not data.

Comment: I do not change the data, I only choose custom format but the format is not changing. It shows the same as it was. The only changes showing is that the Number format box, which is showing "Custom" now which was earlier showing "Date".

Comment: I think, it could not able to track the "date format of cell", since this format is not available in the excel 2007 record. This sheets is provided to me by someone.

Comment: I shared the screenshot from Excel-2007. You have to manually enter the format. Just type `dd-mmm-yyyy` in custom format. **It is not built-in format.**

Comment: Select cells (Containing date values) ---> Right click and choose Format cells ---> Selcet Custome ---> Under `Type` type the format and click ok.

Comment: It could not remove time. I need date only. Your answer did not help me.